# cocoa - Import skype.framework has an error

Tags: macos, cocoa, skype

I have an issue when import skype.framework to mac app.
This is the error

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SkypeAPI", referenced from:
     objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Although, I have added the skype.framework.

Answer (score 1):

The Skype.framework distributed from the Skype developer site does not include the 64-bit version. Download the latest version of the Skype for Mac client, open that app's package contents and copy the Skype.framework (/Skype.app/Contents/Frameworks/Skype.framework) from there and use it to replace the one used by your app. The framework in the current app includes the 64-bit version (though the framework itself hasn't been updated in years). Also be sure that the Skype.framework is copied to your app's internal Frameworks directory during the build phase in Xcode (you may need to add a new build phase script).

Note, though, there are some issues with the SkypeAPI for the last several versions of the Mac client. For instance, the "GET GROUP [id] USERS" call doesn't return anything (not even an error) and "GET SKYPEVERSION" doesn't return the version but does return an error. Also, the Cocoa APIs are asynchronous which can be difficult to parse with complex methods (e.g., get all the GROUP IDs then iterate through them to get a list of all the GROUP names). Other notifications can come in while you're listening for responses to your queries. Calling the API from AppleScript allows synchronous responses but then the managed API client in Skype will just show AppleScript and not your specific app and can be a security issue for users as they will need to accept AppleScript to manage Skype from your app but this also means that other apps using AppleScript won't need permission to control Skype and could do so without the user even knowing about it (harvesting address book info, account profiles, sending texts, etc.).

Comment: Obtaining a copy of the framework from the Skype application still yields OP's error. I verified the architecture of the framework and it is indeed 64 bit.

Comment: Still works as expected (tested on Xcode 7.3.1 (7D1014) on OS X 10.11.5 (15F34) using the default Cocoa Application project template) as long as you update the Framework Search Paths in the build settings of your project to include the directory containing the Skype.framework (be sure to quote it in case there are spaces in the full path).

Comment: The compile error does not occur unless a function of the Skype framework is called somewhere within the code, such as "[SkypeAPI class];". Otherwise, there are no compile errors.

Comment: It looks like the Skype.framework in the Skype 7.x may be to blame. If you download Skype 6.15:

http://download.skype.com/macosx/Skype_6.15.0.335.dmg

and use the Skype.framework embedded in that version, it contains the 64-bit code and works with the latest version of Skype (7.28 as of this post). This works because, again, Skype hasn't really updated the framework in years.

Answer (score 0):

Make certain the Skype.framework is set to be a member in the target of the app you're trying to build.

Click on "Skype.framework" in the file list of your project and then look in the file inspector.  Here is what it looks like for another file:

[image: Make sure Target Membership is selected for your .m file]

Comment: I'm doing mac os x app, not ios

Comment: ahh, thanks for clarifying! It sounds like you added the framework but not necessarily added it to the target of your project.

Comment: I have checked. This framework is added to the target of my project, but it has still this error

Comment: try this as an experiment: if you build for i386 (32-bit), do you continue to have the missing symbol problem?

Comment: It's still error. I build 32 bit and arch i386 like [this image](http://www.imagetoo.com/images/screenawa.png)

Comment: I know the reason. Because Skype.framework/Skype is ppc architecture. Do you know where can get new skype framework?

Comment: ok, thanks for your help. I get it from skype application. And this error is fixed